# -webkit-overflow-scrolling touch doesnt work with fixed elements

Tags: scroll, touch, fixed, device

I use an additional stylesheet that says the following to touch devices:

```
.touch{
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

It works almost perfectly. The problem is that all fixed elements don't actually stay fixed during scrolling. When scrolling is stopped, they get positioned the right way again, but during scrolling they stay in the place where they last were.

Does anyone have any experience with this? thank you.